# How to use await in this scenario

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a method shown bellow

```
 static public async Task GetStudentDetails(studentinfo stu)
 {
   // here i am using webservice call
   // do some other operations
 }
```

and this method is called from another method as shown below:

```
static public void GetUIWindow((int a, int b)
{
  someanothercall();
  studentinfo s = new Studentinfo();
  GetStudentDetails(s); // here how can i use await keyword ??
}
```

Here how can i use await keyword ??

Comment: `await` can only be used on methods marked `async` and returning a task. In your case you can do `GetStudentDetails(s).RunSynchronously();` if you want to wait for your method to wait synchronously without blocking the UI thread.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee have you tried your suggestion? AFAIK invoking the `RunSynchronously` method of a promise-stype task results invariably in a runtime exception.

Answer (score 4):

> how can i use await keyword ??

You `await` the task returned from `GetStudentDetails`:

```
await GetStudentDetails(s);
```

The compiler will then complain at you saying that you should change `GetUIWindow` to be `async` and return a `Task`. So go ahead and do that:

```
static public async Task GetUIWindowAsync(int a, int b)
```

Then do the same for all the places that call `GetUIWindow`. Rinse and repeat; it's [`async` all the way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#async-all-the-way).